# React extract param from url using Match not working

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to access parameters in URL but not bale to get them.
`console.log(User);` gives me undefined.
The url looks like this `http://localhost:3000/data/Auto/90293/22/Female`

> Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined  AT THIS LINE   `return <h1>Hello {match.params}!</h1>`

```
class Customers2 extends Component
{
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        const User = ({ match }) => {
            return <h1>Hello {match.params}!</h1>
        };
        console.log(User);
        console.log("Bhai Print hoja");
        console.log(window.location.href);
        return (
                <div>
                    <User/>
                    <h1>bhaui bhai</h1>
                </div>
        )
    }
 }
```

Comment: Is it normal that you don't close the parenthesis of return?

Comment: Fixed it tya so much

Comment: show your router implementation

Comment: you're not passing anything to User, so you'll need to use ```this.props.match.params.id``` replace id with whatever you put as the variable ```/:id```

Comment: The entire Code is shown on this link. the useful files are customers.jsx and customers2.jsx           https://codesandbox.io/s/ll4wwn6v4q

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
    var User = function( match ){
      {console.log(match)}
      return <h1>Hello {match.params}!</h1>
    };
    var match = {
      params:"ho gea"
    }
    console.log(User);
    console.log("Bhai Print hoja");
    console.log(window.location.href);
    return (
      <div>
      {User(match)}
        <h1>bhaui bhai</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I think this is what you want your code to be. You will pass the match object and then give it to function User which will return you heading.

Comment: It's about path variables